# Input tag type button value update in all open browsers at Runtime in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I Need to update a button value in `Mango DB` in `Meteor`.What i am did here is as given below:

- In Program One `Button` there and the value is **NULL** initially
- When ever clicks the **NULL** `Button`  then the button value **Change to UPDATED** .

The Problem is **The button value Update was not shows in all opened browsers and it shows only current browser**.

I'm not familiar with `Meteor JS`.So Please check the below code once and suggest me how to do.

HTML Code :

```
<head>
  <title>App 1.3</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> uname}}
  {{> main}}
  {{> games }}
</body>

<template name="uname">
<h1>Welcome to App</h1>
<p id="pname"><b>User Name :</b> <input type="text" id="uname" ></p>
</template>  

<template name="main">
<p id="pno"><b>Layout Number :</b> <input type="button" id="no" val =""></p>
     <div name="main"></div>
</template>

<template name="games">

     {{#each game}}

    <div>{{bval}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

JS Code :

```
BtnValues= new Meteor.Collection('btnvalues');

var ButtonValue= "";
var Value = "UPDATED";
var val = "";
if (Meteor.isClient)
 {


  Template.main.events
  ({
    'click input' : function ()
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'

        var  name = document.getElementById('uname');
         console.log(name.value);


         var btnval = document.getElementById('no');

        if(btnval.value == '' && btnid != "no" )
        {
        btnval.value = Value;
            var myBtnData = BtnValues.findOne();
            BtnValues.update( {_id: myBtnData._id},{ $set:{bval :  btnval } });

        }
     }
  });


}
if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function () 
  {
    // code to run on server at startup

     BtnValues.insert({bval : val});

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
<input type="button" id="no" val ="">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="no" val ="{{btnValue}}">
```

And add the following helper in Meteor.Client

```
Template.main.helpers({
  btnValue: function(){
    return BtnValues.findOne();
  })
});
```

Comment: How to give val ="{{btnValue}}" like this at runtime in js?   newButton = document.createElement('input'); newButton.value = '//Here how to write ?';@waitingkuo

Comment: I Needed Initially button value as null and when ever click button then change button value at runtime & update button value as all opened browsers also .so please help me.@waitingkuo